# Neo4j becomes extremely slow after serving a query

Tags: ruby, neo4j, cypher, slowdown, neography

I have a medium-sized neo4j database with about 700000 nodes and 1-5 outgoing relations on each node.

If I use browser interface for querying nodes on indexed attribute and finding adjacent nodes, it takes about 1500ms, which is fine for me.

```
MATCH (n {id_str : 'some_id'})-->(child) return child.id_str
...
Returned 2 rows in 1655 ms
```

But if I run a similar Cypher query mentioning relations using Ruby Neography library it tooks a couple of minutes to complete.

```
lookup_links = "MATCH (n {id_str : {id_str}})-[:internal_link]->(child) return child.id_str"
links = @neo.execute_query(lookup_links, :id_str => id_str)
```

And after that regular browser queries become extremely slow too, taking about two minutes each.

```
MATCH (n2 {id_str : 'some_id'})-->(child) return child.id_str
Returned 2 rows in 116201 ms
```

I run the experiments on 64bit ubuntu 14.04 laptop with 8GB ram and 1GB heap for neo4j. Neo4j version is 2.1.3 installed from official deb packet. Neography version is 1.6.0. I use MRI-1.9.3.

I've done a stackdump using kill -3 while neo is busy serving the query.
https://gist.github.com/akamaus/a06bc9e04c7209c480e9

Any Ideas what's going wrong and how to investivate it?

Comment: Can you please also share your messages.log via a gist? It looks as if it's running out of memory.

Comment: Also you should really use labels and indexed properties, to get decent performance.

Comment: Adding a label to n2 indeed fixed the issue! I've created an index for id_str long ago but I was unaware what explicit label is needed to make use of it. Thanks :)

Comment: I can't find messages.log on hdd. Are any alternative names for it?

Comment: No just that, it should be in `data/graph.db/message.log`